# Getting kernel crash from matrix operations

Tags: crash

I have the following:

```
BBB = BBBBsparse + Transpose[BBBBsparse];
BB = BBB - DiagonalMatrix[Plus @@ BBB];
```

where `BBBBsparse` is a 1553 by 1553 `SparseArray` with diagnal elements as zero.

When I execute this with a whole bunch of code, it works normally, but when I tried to look at the `BB` matrix, it doesn't show anything. It makes a system noise and just exits. From that time it is not even showing the suggestions (like when we type something it automatically shows some suggestions) and all the global variables are lost. So I have to rerun the program again to watch other variables. But when i try to see that `BB` again, it does the same.

I am not sure what the problem is. I have tried it with

```
BB=Normal[BBB]-Normal[DiagonalMatrix[Plus@@BBB]]
```

But the result is the same.

Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Comment: Symptoms point towards a kernel crash of some sort.

Comment: [Didn't see anything unusual here (Windows 10 64bit + MMA 10.2)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyuzy.png).

Comment: Which version/platform are you using?

Comment: Windows7,8GB RAM, 32 bit, MMA-10.2